# How to get integration test coverage for a typescript node application?

Tags: typescript, rest, integration-testing, istanbul, nyc

I have a backend of a web application in typescript and a set of integration tests that run as a separate process, calling the rest API of the web application. I would like to know what share of code of the web application is covered by the integration tests.

I have been struggling with this for a few days now and wonder if I am using the right tools and the right approach. I am trying to use `nyc`, specifically I run `nyc instrument` on my webapp source code. It generates minified, instrumented version of my web app, still in typescript. This works for me.

Then I try to use the standard `tsc` compiler to compile this instrumented code. This I struggle with, the code does not want to compile.

Then I would run the compiled, instrumented webapp and start the integration tests, hoping that the instrumented backend will be generating raw coverage data as it gets hit by the REST requests from the tests. I would then be using `nyc` to turn the raw data into a coverage report.

I would like to confirm that the steps I take make sense at all.